# Счетчик просмотров

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы социалки не действовали на локальные evet'ы? Например, код социалок:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f37e9873b3aa789"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Или вот ссылка  https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.TzfphbFmKYs
ну а вот собственно мой php

```
<?
session_start();
include("blocks/bd.php"); 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id = $_GET['id'];}
if (!isset($id)) {header("Location: man.php");}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,date,author,view,id,title,text,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments_m AS c WHERE c.post=n.id) AS count_coment FROM man AS n WHERE id='$id'",$db);
if (!$result)
{
echo "<p>Запрос из базы данных не прошел!<br> Код ошибки:</p>";
exit (mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(!isset($_SESSION['view'][$id])){
mysql_query ("UPDATE man SET view= view + 1 WHERE id='".$id."'",$db); 
$_SESSION['view'][$id] = $id;
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>Информация не может быть извлечена</p>";
exit();
}
?>
```

у меня так получается что они влияют на просмотры на моем сайте надо бы как то это предотвратить

Comment: Что за социалки?

Comment: панель соц кнопок вот ссылка https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.TzfphbFmKYs

Comment: У вас через $id можно сделать SQL-инъекцию.

Comment: как и как это зафиксить